# How to make this query run in HQL

Tags: grails, hql

update Account_Phone set is_Primary_Phone=(case when account_id=10 and phone_id=20 then is_Primary_Phone=true else is_Primary_Phone=false end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE syntax is: `CASE {operand} WHEN {test_value} THEN {match_result} ELSE {miss_result} END` See the Hibernate [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3099) documentation.

You can also do: `CASE WHEN {test_value} THEN {match_result} ELSE {miss_result} END`

What you **cannot** do is assign the value within the *{match_result}* or *{miss_result}*: `... THEN isPrimaryPhone = true ELSE isPrimaryPhone = false END`

Booleans are handled differently by different database systems. But generally your query's CASE expression would be: `CASE WHEN account_id = :account AND phone_id = :phone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Here's a full example:

```
def hql = """
UPDATE AccountPhone 
SET isPrimaryPhone = CASE WHEN account_id = :account AND phone_id = :phone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
WHERE account_id = :account
"""

AccountPhone.executeUpdate(hql, [account: account.id, phone: params.long('phoneNo')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow two ways:

The first way: Encapsulated your query in an ocject Query (of hibernate) and use execute method. (Account_Phone must be a class mapped with a real table)

The second way: Apply the logic on a set of your class and then use session.merge (or session.saveOrUpdate) to update your DB.

Comment: I have class but  compiler give an error on 'then' world in hql query as follow    AccountPhone.executeUpdate("update AccountPhone set isPrimaryPhone=(Case when (account_id=? and phone_id=?) then isPrimaryPhone=true else isPrimaryPhone=false end) where account_id=?",[account.id,params?.long('phoneNo')])

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: = near line 1, column 118 [update com.express.trade.AccountPhone set isPrimaryPhone=(Case when (account_id=? and phone_id=?) then isPrimaryPhone=true else isPrimaryPhone=false end) where account_id=?]

Comment: First: instead of true / false try with 1 / 0; second: Have you replaced your parameters? Try without parameters (put constants in your query and then try with parameters)

Answer (score 0):

in  Grails 3.0.9 i add do this to the query

AccountPhone.executeUpdate("update AccountPhone ap set ap.isPrimaryPhone=case when (account_id=? and phone_id=?) **THEN true  ELSE  false** end where account_id=?",[account.id,params?.long('phoneNo'),account.id])